# How can I make my banner span the whole width of the site

Tags: html, css

Currently got the following setup by checking out other previously asked questions, although now I'm stuck as it won't span out

Comment: please share your website link

Comment: what is `left: 0px` doing?

Comment: `.banner {display: block;}`

Answer (score 1):

you mean you want it to extend to full screen width? if so you need to make its parent element width `100%` too for example

```
body {
       width: 100%;
}
```

it could be another parent like a div.container or whatever..

Comment: When extending the body also the whole site shifts left, is there anyway of centering the main body?

Comment: without seeing your entire markup and css it's gonna be just a guess from my side but try doing this `body { width : 100%; margin: 0 auto;}` this center the entire body and hopefully its content but if there are other css  rules interfering this won't work

Answer (score 0):

for 100% width of span

```
<style type="text/css">
.banner span{
  width: 100% !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add img inside as this.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <header class="banner">
    <div class="banner-wrapper">
      <div class="banner-title">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/81/Williams_Companies_logo.svg/1280px-Williams_Companies_logo.svg.png" height="100px" width="100%">
      </div>
      <nav class="banner-nav">
            {{ portal | welcome_navigation }}
      </nav>
    </div>
      <nav class="nav-menu" id="header-tabs">
      <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu-title"><a href="https://www.TEST.co.uk" class="nav-links">Back to Main Site</a></li>
        <li class="nav-contact">| Questions? Get in touch: <li class="nav-number">12345568693</li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually has nothing to do with the width, as header elements are already supposed to span the whole width. There must be some default margin or padding in your html body. All you need to do is set default margin and padding on body tag to be 0. 
(I usually follow setting margin/padding on body to 0 as a general practice)

You can remove your existing css code and replace it with this (I checked, it's working):

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="banner">
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <div class="banner-title">
      {{ portal | logo }}
    </div>
    <nav class="banner-nav">
      {{ portal | welcome_navigation }}
    </nav>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-menu" id="header-tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-menu-title"><a href="https://www.TEST.co.uk" class="nav-links">Back to Main Site</a></li>
      <li class="nav-contact">| Questions? Get in touch:
        <li class="nav-number">12345568693</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```